# Replaced the CPU but PC doesn't start

Tags: cpu, hp, compaq-desktop-computer, intel

I bought this CPU (Intel Core i7 870 Processor Quad Core 2.93GHz 95W LGA 1156 8M Cache Desktop CPU
) on Aliexpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004371446180.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.11.18b31802YWNZwl

I want to use it to replace the old i5 processor on my HP desktop. Detailed information about my desktop can be found in the attached CPU-Z report (both the text and screenshots)

After installing it, I hear beeps every sec for six times then there is a one-second break then it beeps again. I have tried resetting the BIOS by removing the motherboard battery and pressing and holding the SW50 yellow button.

Do you think that it is an issue with the CPU (that I can return) or a compatibility issue with the motherboard..? I am not able to find the motherboard information from the CPU-Z report to look up the supported CPU list.

Thanks!
Difan

[image]
CPU-Z report - https://www.dropbox.com/s/m25h4b2sls791kz/DESKTOP-P0FP5LP.txt?dl=0

Comment: One thing to check is whether your motherboard has the latest BIOS.

Comment: What makes you think your new processor is compatible with this motherboard? They are entirely two different generations of Intel processors.

Comment: Model of HP desktop?

Comment: According to this info that processor is compatible>>>>http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/specs-hewlett-packard-304ah/

Comment: 6 beeps indicate a video issue, check the video card for proper seating it is has one.

Comment: It appears they are the same generation but the power requirements might be is the deciding factor of compatibility. Compatibility during that generation was complicated.

Comment: Sorry, I never thought it would be this complex... I thought that as long as the socket matches, the CPU would be compatible... My desktop is HP Compaq 8100 Elite SFF PC. I would appreciate it if someone can give me a deterministic answer on whether it would be compatible or not.. I know it might be difficult for branded PC. And I will upgrade the BIOS tonight (with my old CPU). Thanks all for your response!

Comment: Dealing with the first gen processors - the noticable difference between an i5/i7 isn't that much. Either stick with your current processor or buy something newer from HP 6th gen or above. Make sure it has M2 SATA slot as this does make a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the HP tech specification here http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02034672
That processor should work.
[image]

The error code states video as **the processor you have purchased does not have video capibilities built in** - The 8100 SFF does have the ability to add a video card via the spare pcie slot - half height video cards should fit.

Comment: Appreciate your input! Will purchase a video card and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Johnny, if you mind me asking, will this video card work? It's pci-e x16 and it can connect two monitors which is what I need. Thanks! https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004069725052.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.1.2b583ce21oqWvM&algo_pvid=bd627364-2821-47ed-89ac-2457ef69a9db&algo_exp_id=bd627364-2821-47ed-89ac-2457ef69a9db-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000029069274847%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21CAD%21162.64%2163.43%21%21%21%21%21%40211bda9b16732335235902014d0706%2112000029069274847%21sea&curPageLogUid=kr1YvDRouKLT?

Comment: Please read all the info I give you - Half height video adapters should fit - Look for half height video adapters - The one you linked to is full height.

Comment: Sorry Johnny... I saw it but it just went over my head lol. I researched and half height = low profile, correct? I will choose one that is LP + PCIe 2 x16 card. Thanks again.